# Google People API Delete Contact: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-people-api

I'm trying to update a contact information with Google People API but I'm getting the following response:

```
    Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 *
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
protected static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    final InputStream in = GooglePeopleAPI.class.getResourceAsStream("/google/client_secret.json");
    final GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    final GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}
```

After getting the credential I initialize the PeopleService

```
/**
 * Build and return an authorized People client service.
 * @return an authorized People client service
 */
public static PeopleService getPeopleService() {
    try {
        return new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, authorize())
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new GoogleException("", "Não foi possível criar uma instância do PeopleService", ex);
    }
}
```

And finally do the API call

```
PEOPLE_SERVICE
                    .people()
                    .deleteContact("contact id")
                    .execute();
```

I'm able to read all the contacts but I can't delete/update any of them. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the scopes in your `SCOPES` variable? Are you using the readonly contacts `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly` scope? If so you need to use the write contacts scope for deletion `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts`. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/deleteContact)

Comment: I'm using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts` scope but the problem is still there.